# Cannot Load Type on Mono Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, openshift, .net-assembly

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 4 website with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. The site works well on my Windows machine, but the real problem occurs whenever I upload my application to a RedHat Linux server. The server kernel version is `2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64` and it runs Mono 3.0.7. Hosting is provided by [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) running the [Mono](https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-community-cartridge-mono) cartridge.

It used to run my application just fine on Linux (a few weeks ago), but since then I have made many changes to the application (not the server). I did not change the required .NET runtime. It displays this error when I load the home page:

[image]

It says that it cannot locate the core business-logic class that I created to construct my home page, `OpenShift.Business.Home.Introduction`. The namespace and class name is correct, as it worked on Windows. The Openshift assembly that it uses is present, I checked the Linux file system. The error logs from Mono are not helpful for this issue.

Does anyone know how to begin resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `.gitignore` file was not pushing up any of the DLLs in my `bin` folder. So they existed, on my local Windows machine, but were never pushed to the Linux server. I removed that folder from `.gitignore`, committed and pushed again, and everything works just like it did on Windows.